# Is there a more elegant way to detect touch events support and assign either a "click" or "touchend" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

```
var ClickOrTouchEvent = ("ontouchend" in document.documentElement ? "touchend" : "click");

$("#MyButton").on(ClickOrTouchEvent, function () {
  // Do something
});
```

This works, but there is probably a more elegant way to detect touch events support and assign either a "click" or "touchend" event.

Comment: Your solution works until you have to use the event parameter. MouseEvent and TouchEvent are very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of plugins that people have created to add more advanced touch support to their jquery based web apps like drag and drop.  You can use one of those instead of trying to make your own.

That said they all seem to have their weird issues in my experience so you will probably have to tweek.  Looks like your solution is in the same family as most of theirs.  Here are a couple popular plugins and the solutions they employ for deciding touch or click:

[TouchPunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) adds touch to everything like so:

```
// Detect touch support and save it in support
  $.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;

  // Ignore browsers without touch support
  if (!$.support.touch) {
    return;
  }
//rest of plugin code follows
```

[jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) has a method you have to call to add touch events to the desired element... but only if the browser supports it.

```
// Same deal. Detect touch support and save it in support
$.extend($.support, {
        touch: "ontouchend" in document
});

//
// Hook up touch events
//
$.fn.addTouch = function() {
        if ($.support.touch) {
                this.each(function(i,el){
                        el.addEventListener("touchstart", iPadTouchHandler, false);
                        el.addEventListener("touchmove", iPadTouchHandler, false);
                        el.addEventListener("touchend", iPadTouchHandler, false);
                        el.addEventListener("touchcancel", iPadTouchHandler, false);
                });
        }
};



....
```

Then call addTouch on the elements with jQuery UI functions applied:

```
$('Element').dialog().addTouch();
```

Comment: What if I'm not using jQuery UI for anything and I just want straight up Javascript/jQuery solution?

Comment: Then I think your solution is fine.  What I was trying to point out is that some very popular frameworks test for touch compatibility in the same way that you are.  The only difference being that they are using jquery.support and some more advanced init.

Comment: I would not recommend detecting the touch event *support*. Instead, it's better to detect if touch event *has been used* (e.g., disable the effect of click handler on touchstart). Problem with detecting touch support is that browsers may support both touch and mouse (e.g., laptop with touch screen) or even claim to support touch events on a non-touch device.